# Calculating if ordered quantity is not equal to package

Tags: python

In my case, I'm selling the product's in packages. 1 package is 24 products if I order 30 than it is more than 1 package but less then 2 so I'm raising an error for a user to know that he is ordering more than one package and less then two. But the problem is that this warning should not appear when he is ordering 48,72,96 and so on.. as it equals to 2,3, and 4 full packages. but raise an error if he orders not the full package.  how can I make an algorithm for this?

```
product_qty = 30
packaging_qty = 24

def check_unpacking_allowence(self):
    if product_qty / packaging_qty != 1:
        raise UserError('You cant break packaging')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
product_qty = 30
packaging_qty = 24

def check_unpacking_allowence(self):
    if product_qty % packaging_qty != 0:
        raise UserError('You cant break packaging')
```